# When I use <input> the GET method works, but javascript doesn't

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

And vice versa...

I have a button that submits user input. For whatever reason I set it with `<a>` tags instead of `<button>`. Code worked so I never noticed. I later needed to use php's GET method so I changed the `<a>` to `<input>` and the GET method then applied the query strings to the url like I wanted, but the javascript code doesn't execute now like it did when I was using `<a>` tags for the submit button.

Also, jsfiddle says to use the POST method after the example runs, but I want to the query strings for bookmarking so that is not an option.

Example with `<input>` tags (I don't know how to load Twitter Bootstrap 3 on here so the code doesn't actually work on jsfiddle)
http://jsfiddle.net/u4GW7/

Any ideas why one would work while the other doesn't?

Comment: It's either or, you can use a regular form submit to send the data, but then the page reloads and changes made by the javascript is generally lost, or you can make changes with javascript, but then you can't submit the form and change the URL, as that requires a page reload. There are many other solutions, but they are more complicated, such as the History API to change the URL, or using a hash instead of a querystring etc.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to submit form (basically reload page) and run javascript code. 

You could run code when page loads (after form submit). To know when to run code or not you could check for input via PHP and include JS file that will fire up your code, or use cookies, or something else... or just use ajax to submit form.

Comment: Thanks @ntatic for the info. I think ajax might be where I want to go from here.